# Unexplained Unresponsiveness on Very Powerful Machine

Tags: performance

I've got a pretty large blend file (~2GB), containing a couple objects with large meshes. On my home computer with Blender 2.9, the UI is perfectly responsive in object mode.

I have a access to a machine with 256 GB main memory, an 88 core Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2699 v4 CPU, and 3 RTX GPU's. So I installed Blender 3.0, and loaded the blend file.  But Blender is unresponsive, taking about 30 seconds or so for an action (e.g. clicking on the file menu) to respond.

The system is using an SSD, and I've disabled auto-save. I've tried all 3 rendering options, CUDA, CPU, Optix. Only 2 of the 88 cores are busy, and only a tiny fraction of the main memory is being used. The render time is very fast, but it takes 30 seconds for the render menu to open up in the UI and for me to click the render button.

Is there a way I can figure out why this is happening? My home computer only has an I3 CPU and a mid-range graphics card and can handle it fine.

Comment: Not sure why that would happen, though i think i know the reason. blender application, in itself, is a single core software. only the rendering is multi core (that is, if you want it to be). this might explain this anomaly.